# jQuery ajax/load getting slower and slower

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following function to load content into `#canvas` on click:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

    jQuery('.tabs a').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    });

    jQuery('#blog').on('click',function(e) {
        jQuery('#canvas').load('blog.php');
    });
    jQuery('#news').on('click',function(e) {
        jQuery('#canvas').load('news.php');
    });
    jQuery('#gallery').on('click',function(e) {
        jQuery('#canvas').load('gallery.php');
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
     <a id="blog">Blog</a>
     <a id="news">News</a>
     <a id="gallery">Gallery</a>
</ul>

<div id="canvas"></div>
```

This works fine when the tabs are clicked the first few times. However, the more times the tabs are clicked, the slower the content is loaded into #canvas. Eventually, the #canvas content starts to flick in and out between each page.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

I have tried replacing the load method with ajax and set caching to false, however the problem persists:

```
jQuery('#blog').on('click',function(e) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'blog.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            jQuery('#canvas').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are connecting event handlers *inside the Ajax completion event*, so each time you run an Ajax call you will have multiple event handlers attached to your elements. 1 then 2, then 3, then 4 handlers etc doing the same thing on each one. This unwanted repetition will eventually slow your page to a crawl.

Use *delegated event handlers* outside your Ajax call.

e.g.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.tabs a',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '#blog', function(e) {
    jQuery('#canvas').load('blog.php');
});
jQuery(document).on('click', '#news', function(e) {
    jQuery('#canvas').load('news.php');
});
jQuery(document).on('click', '#gallery',function(e) {
    jQuery('#canvas').load('gallery.php');
});
```

You do not then need the `jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){` at all.

Delegated event handlers work by listening for an event (e.g. `click`) to bubble up to an ancestor element (`document` is the default if nothing else is closer/convenient). It then applies the jQuery selector at event time, so the item only needs to exists then. It then applies the event's callback function to only the matching elements that caused the event.

note: do not use `body` for delegated events as it has a serious bug.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the explanation and example. That seems to have fixed the problem.